# Best way to dynamically replace some values of a struct by other values of that struct in an Echo query

Tags: elixir

I have a function:

```
def listAll(dataSchema, fields) do                                 
    dataSchema |> order() |> Repo.all()
end
```

that returns a query result that looks like this:

```
[%Skeleton.Data.Evento{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "eventos">,
  date: "dewfwef", date_de: nil, date_es: nil, date_fr: nil, date_pt: nil,
  id: nil, inserted_at: nil, text: "hello", text_de: nil,
  text_es: nil, text_fr: "Bonjour", text_pt: "Olá", title: "Good morning", title_de: nil, title_es: nil, title_fr: nil, title_pt: "Bom dia"},
 %Skeleton.Data.Evento{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "eventos">,
  date: "ds", date_de: nil, date_es: nil, date_fr: nil, date_pt: nil, id: nil,
  inserted_at: nil, text: "Bye", text_de: nil, text_es: nil,
  text_fr: nil, text_pt: "Adeus", title: "Good evening", title_de: nil, title_es: nil, title_fr: nil, title_pt: "Boa noite"}]
```

`fields` is a list that can contain any number of keys:

```
fields = [:date_pt, :text_pt, :title_pt]
```

How to replace all the values of `date, text, title` (the same key name but without suffix) by the values of `text_pt` (or whatever key/keys passed in the `fields` argument) automatically?
Note that we don't know upfront which keys we have as they are passed as arguments on a case by case situation and that I would like to do this in the Ecto query, not in the resulting list of structs.

Comment: Why not dynamically access the field(s) you need instead of replacing them? So instead, call `my_event[text_language_field]` where `text_language_field` is one of `:text`, `:text_de`, `:text_es`, etc. You already seem to have that information in your `fields` variable.

Comment: @JustinWood Yes, but doing it like I was asking allow me to simplify my templates as I will always only have to call `i.text` when iterating through the data being sure that it will contain the translation I want because it is being copied in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do this, assuming fields contains a `locale` key with a string, e.g. `"pt"`:

```
def listAll(dataSchema, %{locale: locale}) do                                 
    text_field = :"text_#{locale}"
    dataSchema
    |> select([m], %{m | text: field(m, ^text_field)})
    |> order()
    |> Repo.all()
end
```

This will replace the value of `text` with the value of the dynamically calculated field `text_field`.

Note: You should make sure the `locale` is validated at some point with a whitelist. If the user can send arbitrary locales, creating that atom can crash the VM. That : interpolation is equivalent to `String.to_atom("text_#{locale}")`.

---

For the edited question: the function's API looks weird to me. There is probably a way better approach to do what you want to achieve. But if you really need to do it this way, here's the simplest way I can think of right now:

```
def listAll(dataSchema, fields) do                                 
  dataSchema
  |> select([m], %{m | text: field(m, ^text_field)})
  |> order()
  |> Repo.all()
  |> Enum.map(fn record ->
    Enum.reduce(fields, record, fn field, record ->
      # You might want to replace the Regex with something faster like `:binary.match` + `:binary.part` since you only need to find a '_' and remove everything after that.
      without_suffix = field |> Atom.to_string |> String.replace(~r/_.*/, "") |> String.to_existing_atom
      Map.put(record, without_suffix, Map.get(record, field))
    end)
  end)
end
```

Comment: Sorry but only now I realised that I din'd fully explain my needs. I've just edited the question.

Comment: Dogbert is possible contact you in private?

Comment: @Dogbert You're right. Nevertheless every time I stumble upon an issue I try to understand a solution from my perspective and compare it to experts own view so that I really learn. Also, I think that these questions (I mean your great answers) may become a very good guide for newcomers to Elixir and Phoenix, so by asking them we're documenting them (and it also allows me to track my evolution when after some time I look into what were my issues) :) So, thank you very much!